# Order of events in page using devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

Can you please tell me the order of executing standard events on page? (I's using devexpress aspx.net components) Like Page_Load, Page_Init and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically looking for the order of execution of page events, which you can have from following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I knew this article, but thought there could be somth else.